# Does a text parameter in Reporting Services map to SQL Parameter varchar or nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm analyzing a deadlock issue with Reporting Services.  I can't find any reference to the datatypes of parameters in Reporting Services and how they map to SQL Server params.

I have some text params in Reporting Services, and I don't know if they are coming across as varchar or nvarchar (ANSI string or String in .NET)

Comment: I just don't have access to profiler right now in our enterprise.  Working on it.  One thing I have discovered though, is params are all coming across as  nvarchar(4000) even for Date fields and others.  I've verified that they are defined as DateTime in the Reporting Service dataset.

Comment: text = varchar, ntext = nvarchar.  "text" is a deprecated type, and has been replaced by "varchar(max)" (and ntext by nvarchar(max)). Just FYI.